# Retrieve roles from Power BI Report using an API

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, row-level-security

I have a Power BI report that enabled Row-Level Security (RLS). I'm trying to integrate it into a web application using the embed method. In order to generate the embed token, the request body should be as below.

import axios from "axios";

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${groupID}/reports/${reportID}/GenerateToken`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Bearer '
  },
  data: '{accessLevel: 'View', "identities": [{"username": '', "reports": [''], "roles": [''], "datasets": ['']}]}'
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

As you can see I need to get the username, report ID, roles and datasets. Getting username, report ID and dataset ID is fine. I can use a few APIs to get that information. But, the issue is with getting the user role.

At the moment, I'm using the below API to get userroles.

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/workspaces/scanResult/{scanId}
```

**However, it needs the scan ID and I'm using the below API to get the scan ID. but, sometimes I'm not getting the expected response from that API. Looks like it needs some time to fetch data.**

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/workspaces/getInfo?lineage=True&datasourceDetails=False&datasetSchema=True&datasetExpressions=True
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/workspace-info-post-workspace-info

[image]

If someone know a different solution or a solution to this, please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a Polling step additionally, where you need to wait for the Scan Status to be Succeeded.

Use this REST API [Admin - WorkspaceInfo GetScanStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/admin/workspace-info-get-scan-status) to get the Scan Status. Once the status is Succeeded, you can get the scan result for the specified scan using the API you mentioned.

Comment: Can I know how to implement a polling step for this? The API we have to get the scan status is a REST API. I googled, but couldn't find any examples.

Comment: If you want a reference for polling step, Refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/KotanaSai21/63e585284b1f5045ef2a154b76ea380f) file. Although in the gist we implemented export report to pdf, we need to wait until the report is ready for download and we get the status from REST API. It will be similar to implement a polling step and verify the scan status.

Comment: LMK if this helps or not ?

Comment: Let me check this.